# converting one line string into individual integers

Tags: java

if i have this line in a file: 2 18 4 3
and i want to read it as individual integers, how could i?

i'm using bufferreader:

```
BufferedReader(new FileReader("mp1.data.txt"));
```

i have tried to use:

```
BufferedReader(new RandomAccessFile("mp1.data.txt"));
```

so i can use the method

```
.readCahr();
```

but i got an error

if i use

```
int w = in.read();
```

it will read the ASCII, and i want it as it is(in dec.)

i was thinking to read it as a string first, but then could i separate each number?

also i was thinking to let each number in a line, but the file i have is long with numbers

Comment: [Scanner#nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) could work.

Comment: Read the line into a string called line. Then use String[] values = line.split(" "); then convert each value to an int

Answer (score 5):

Consider using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("mp1.data.txt"));
```

You can then use [`scan.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) (which returns an `int`, not a `String`) so long as [`scan.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29).

No need for that ugly splitting and parsing :)

*However*, note that this approach will continue reading integers past the first line (if that's not what you want, you should probably follow the suggestions outlined in the other answers for reading and handling only a single line).

Furthermore, `hasNextInt()` will return `false` as soon as a non-integer is encountered in the file. If you require a way to detect and handle invalid data, you should again consider the other answers.

Comment: Personally I'm not a fan of the `Scanner` API. My experience of Stack Overflow questions is that it's all too easy to use badly. I think the splitting and parsing is cleaner than `Scanner` here: it ensures that you only get the integers from *one* line, and lets you know how many of those there are. How does your solution work if the next line *also* has integers in? And how does it indicate failure?

Comment: @JonSkeet Like anything, it depends on the greater context of what the OP is really trying to do. His problem description, at least in my mind, was indicative of a scenario for which `Scanner` was specifically designed. If the OP requires the features you detailed, then he can by all means continue using the `BufferedReader`, but mentioning `Scanner` seamed reasonable.

Comment: Well, he said he has "this line in a file" with no indication that it's the *only* line in the file. I can think of more situations in which this solution is *inappropriate* than situations where it's the best approach. There's a lot that can go wrong here, and you didn't mention any of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Alright, I understand where you're coming from. I edited to include your point on the multiple lines with integers. What else would you say can go wrong?

Comment: There can be non-integers on the line you're trying to read - at which point your code will just silently stop, whereas the split/parse will throw an exception, which I believe is a better approach to invalid data.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well you've enlightened me, I suppose. I edited to include that, but I'll delete this answer if the OP indicates it doesn't work for him. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to approach larger problems in software engineering by breaking them into smaller ones. In this case, you've got three tasks:

1. Read a line from the file
2. Break it into individual parts (still strings)
3. Convert each part into an integer

Java makes each of these simple:

1. Use [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader#readLine%28%29) to read the line as a string first
2. It looks like the splitting is as simple as splitting by a space with [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

   ```
   String[] bits = line.split(" ");
   ```

   If that's not good enough, you can use a more complicated regular expression in the `split` call.
3. Parse each part using [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Another option for the splitting part is to use the `Splitter` class from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/). Personally I prefer that, but it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split()` the String and then use the `Integer.parseInt()` method in order to convert all the elements to `Integer` objects.

```
try {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mp1.data.txt"));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String[] split = line.split("\\s");
     for (String element : split) {
        Integer parsedInteger = Integer.parseInt(element);
        System.out.println(parsedInteger);
     }
   }
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("Error: " + e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you read the line using `BufferedReader`, you can use `String.split(regex)` method to split the string by space `("\\s")`.

```
    for(String s : "2 18 4 3".split("\\s")) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7+, you can use this utility method:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
for (String line: lines) {
    String[] numbers = line.split("\\s+");
    int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
try{
    // Open the file that is the first 
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        //split line by whitespace 
        String[] ints = strLine.split(" ");

        int[] integers = new int[ints.length];

        // to convert from string to integers - Integer.parseInt ("123")
        for ( int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            integers[i] = Integer.parseInt(ints[i]);
        }
        // now do what you want with your integer
        // ...
    }
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```